# Discord Python: How do i safe a User Name/ID in a variable so i can use it to adjust their roles

Tags: python, discord.py

Im working on a Russian Rulette function, im using this to safe the Username so i can later pick the right user and mute him

```
user = ctx.author.mention
players = list()
players.append(user)




@client.command()
async def roll(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    winner = random.choice(players)
    send = winner + " won"
    await ctx.send(send)
    global sta
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(winner, speak=False, send_messages=False)
    
    sta = 0
```

But im getting a error:

Command raised an exception: `InvalidArgument: target parameter must be either Member or Role`
How can i safe the User so the code refernces it as an User

Answer (score 1):

The problem you done here is you need to pass a `Member Object` but you are not passing member object. So replace `user = ctx.author.mention` to `user = ctx.author` in the first line of your code.
But I an not sure that you can fix both speak=False and send_message=False because if it is a voice channel you can set speak permission but you cant fix send_message permission in the same way if it is a text channel you can set speak permission but you can set send_message permission. 
So check which type of channel it is and set permissions accordingly

Comment: If it works or it is useful for you can you verify my answer with green check mark please?